# Count occurrences of list items in String Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to achieve this

```
string_list = ["red","blue","green"]
text = "This is a string about my favourite colours like red blue and green but blue is the best"
some_function(string_list,text)

Output: [1,2,1]
```

How do I achieve this? Getting a number which adds all occurrences (4 in this case) is no problem, but I´d like it to be seperated by the string_list items.

Comment: Can you write code to count the occurrences of `red`? of `blue`? of `green`? If you put these things together, why does it not solve the problem? Also, why is this tagged `pandas` - why would the Pandas library be relevant here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
return [text.count(string) for string in string_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `count()` function to count a substring in a string.
Below code may help

```
def get_count(slist,text):
    result=[]
    for string in slist:
        result.append(text.count(string))
    return result
    

string_list = ["red","blue","green"]
text = "This is a string about my favourite colours like red blue and green but blue is the best"

print(get_count(string_list,text))
```

### Output

```
[1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a long way of doing it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

string_list = ["red","blue","green"]
text = "This is a string about my favourite colours like red blue and green but blue is the best"


def count_occurrences(string_list, text):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for string in text.split():
        if string in string_list:
            counts[string] += 1
    return counts.values()

print(count_occurrences(string_list, text))

dict_values([1, 2, 1])
```